# Cocos2d's skew action exceeds itself when there is a framerate hiccup

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

It's simple: I have some sprites that are repeating a Skew action to one side and then the other in my map.

When there is a framerate hiccup, you can see that suddenly the skew exceeds itself - that is, if it should be at `2.0f`, it looks like it is at `50.0f` or something. If you wait a bit, it stabilises alright.

I suspect it is due to a framerate hiccup because it happens in the following scenarios:

- When the phone is locked and then unlocked.
- The application comes to foreground from the background.
- The map scene was frozen in the Director's scene stack (because I used `pushScene`) and then it was resumed (by calling `popScene`).

It doesn't happen always. I've seen it occur in iPhones 4 and 5 - as well as iPads.

Is there a way to control this skew so it doesn't exceed itself ever?

cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

When I had a problem like that it was because CCDirector was not paused properly when backgrounded.. so have you made sure that you are pausing/resuming the director and starting/stopping animation in all the right places?

```
-(void) applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];    
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do seem to have all those callbacks.

Comment: Just noticed you said CC2D 1.0.1 . I'd have a look through the changelogs through 1.1bx to see if there were any changes that may apply. Regardless, it may be worth the time to upgrade to 1.1bx since iirc there weren't that many API changes between 1.0.1 and 1.1bx . Perhaps somewhere in there a relevant bug got squashed?